# Activerecord in rails 3.2 within an engine throws NameError: uninitialized constant when using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines

I am building a rails engine. I have the following two model classes:

```
module LandingPageEng
    class LandingPage < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_protected # just for debugging right now
        has_many :slide_show_images, :dependent => :destroy
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :slide_show_images, allow_destroy: true
    end
end
```

The second class is:

```
module LandingPageEng
    class SlideShowImage < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessible :image, :landing_page_id
        belongs_to :landing_page 

        validates :image, :presence => true
    end
end
```

The tables associated with them are landing_page_eng_landing_page and landing_page_eng_slide_show_image.

When I run the following in the console I get the error NameError: uninitialized constant SlideShowImage.

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > LandingPageEng::LandingPage.new({"title"=>"wd", "tagline"=>"wed",     "slide_show_images"=>{"_destroy"=>""}})
NameError: uninitialized constant SlideShowImage
    from /Users/martinjlogan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-  3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `block in constantize'
    from /Users/martinjlogan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `each'
    from /Users/martinjlogan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:228:in `constantize'
    from /Users/martinjlogan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:54:in `constantize'
<snip>
```

I have been banging my head on this and can't figure it out. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Rails 3 setup with engines to test this on quickly but I think the issue is with your `has_many` configuration; it's looking for a class that's named `SlideShowImage` but your class name is `LandingPageEng::SlideShowImage`.

I believe adding a `:class_name` option to your `has_many` will fix this.

http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.8rc1/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M004956

Comment: Thanks for helping out Ryan. Now I get something rather odd. It seems to now expect the class I specify with :class_name and instead finds an Array??
`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: LandingPageEng::SlideShowImage(#70200876366100) expected, got Array(#70200871589540)`

Comment: Looks like a problem with the params that are getting passed in. Instead of passing in slide_show_image_attributes as a key it is just passing slide_show_images from the form. This same code worked fine outside of an engine. This is progress though. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a problem where multiple variables changed at the same time. Not sure what I did. It is all working now, your solution was correct. Thanks